# reading a file with fscanf in a for loop C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am having a problem reading from a file, the first print outside of the loop is done correctly . but inside the for loop nothing is read from the file. 
I'm looking for an explanation or help if anyone knows what's going on.
(assuming there are n*m strings in the file seperated by " \t\r\n")
Thanks.

```
{

char *file_name{
    char *new_num="    ";
    FILE *ifp=NULL;
    int i, j, n, m;

    ifp =fopen(file_name,"r");
    if (ifp!=NULL)
    {
        fscanf(ifp,"%d %d",&n,&m );

        printf("\n  Data from the file: %d, %d \n",n,m);
    }
for (i=0 ; i< n ;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){

fscanf(ifp,"%s",new_num);
printf("\n new num : %s ",new_num);

    }}
fclose(ifp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Comment: Please fix the formatting and post a complete code, before we even looking at it...

Comment: Your program writes to a string literal, so it at least has that undefined behavior.

Comment: Post lacks compilable code and sample input and expected output.  Providing those makes for a better post.  Review [mcve]

Comment: regarding: `ifp =fopen(file_name,"r");
    if (ifp!=NULL)`  the overall logic says that if the call to `fopen()` fails, then don't execute the code inside the `if()` code block`  Ok so far.  Then, after the `if()` code block, (where it is not known if the call to `fopen()` was successful or not) the code tries to use the value returned from `fopen()`, which may be NULL, to try an access a file.  Strongly suggest the first statements after the call to `fopen()` be: if( !ffp ) { perror( "fopen failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }  // implied else, fopen successful`

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Note: treat the closing brace '}' as a separate statement.

Comment: The pointer: `new_num` points into readonly memory, (Which it cannot write to.

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, including `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: what is `char *file_name{` supposed to be?   It looks much like the beginning of a function (but in C, do not nest functions) and later in the function, `file_name` is referenced, which makes this code recursive.  Both probably not what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read some thing into a variable or pointer you should allocate space.

> ```
> char *new_num="    ";
> ```

Here it writes string in text segment and gives that pointer to new_num.

I made little changes to your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 50

int main()
{
    char *file_name;
    char new_num[SIZE];
    FILE *ifp=NULL;
    int i, j, n, m;

    file_name = "input.txt";
    ifp =fopen(file_name,"r");
    if (ifp!=NULL)
    {
        fscanf(ifp,"%d %d",&n,&m );
        printf("Data from the file: %d, %d \n",n,m);
    }
    for (i=0 ; i< n ;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            fscanf(ifp,"%s",new_num);
            printf("new num : %s\n ",new_num);
        }
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    return 0;
}
```

By interpreting by the name new_num as integer I advice you to use apt data type instead of %s

For that you need to modify the data type of new_num

```
type new_num[SIZE];
```

and inside `fscanf` use apt identifier.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
 char *new_num="    ";

 ...

 fscanf(ifp,"%s",new_num);
```

you are instructing the program to write inside a string. In some systems this string might be immutable, and writing to it would cause an error.

Try perhaps:

```
 char *new_num = NULL;

 ...
 new_num = malloc(1024);
 if (NULL == new_num) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory?\n");
     exit(8);
 }
```

(The above solves a 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' which your code causes on my system, 64 bit Linux with glibc 2.27).

Answer (score 0):

- You assign the pointer new_num to a a string literal and try to modify it. This will cause an error.
- At this statement: char *file_name{ this might be a typo. file_name is not assigned to any string before used.